# Using Elmah and NLog in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, nlog

I'm using Elmah in my MVC4 application for handle exception. Then I installed NLog for debugging. When there is an exception

```
try
{
    // There is exception occured here
}
catch (DataException ex)
{
    logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, dex.Message);
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes");
}
```

Why NLog doesn't log the exception while elmah does?
I want to log the exception using NLog and elmah, how to configure them?

Comment: You'll need to provide the settings from your web.config for this, remember that you need a configuration section at the top (first line or two), and details of the logging further down

Comment: @KerSplosh I already set the web.config, <customerror mode="on"/>, what else?

Comment: you need a node like this at the top of your web.config and a corresponding one further down: <configSections>    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>

Answer (score 2):

I decided to post this as an answer as it was not clear in comments:

[The NLog Documentation](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file) give a desciption of how to construct your web.config (or use a separate configuration file)

You need this block in your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>
  <nlog>
     **** Nlog specific settings go here *****
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

Some example NLog settings:

```
  <variable name="logDirectory" value="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}"/>
  <targets>
    <target name="file1" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/file1.txt"/>
    <target name="file2" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/file2.txt"/>
  </targets>
```

Comment: Finally, I've just found the solution. It is because in try block there is code that throw new Exception() and it is not handled. I only handled for DataException. If I change DataException to Exception, NLog will log the exception. So the point here is handle and unhandled exception. I've just learn it today. The web.config is same with yours, thanks for your response :)